# Entity Framework Add method not available

Tags: mysql, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I created an ADO.NET Entity Data Model from an MySQL database. The model does not have an Add() or Remove() method.

[image: No Add Method]

For connection tot the mysql database I'm using MySQL.DATA v.6.7.4.0 and MySql.Data.Entity v.6.7.4.0. In a Console Project.

Last week I made a project as this one and worked perfectly. But I don't know what I'm missing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would happen if you declared that collection as a read-only collection type (probably `IQuyerable<T>`).

Change it to `DbSet<T>`.

Comment: isn't it an `IQueryable<T>`, as intellisense shows extensions methods for `IQueryable<T>` ? I would guess transportEntities2 is a DbContext, or something like that.

Comment: Maybe you're right, I've  deleted the model and added it for the 8th time. And now it work. Can you tell me where do I find the IEnumerabele<T> declaration in the model ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus yes it was DbContext. And now when it is working it is the same.
Different now is also that Model1.edmx has an Model1.tt.
I also changed the .NET version from 3.5 to 4.5, maybe that was the solution.

Comment: @GeorgesC: Actually, you should probably change it to `DbSet<T>` or `IDbSet<T>`.